# WebService quase 100% (rest/json)

Tags: android, json, web-service, cliente-servidor

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver T_T, após muitas pesquisas criei um webservice (teste), para ser consumido por uma aplicação android.

A única função dele é retornar uma String, mas não sei porque não funciona, pois a String até aparece no logcat, fiz todo o caminho, mas não seta na `TextView`.

Se puderem me dar uma ajuda, serei muito grato, aí vai o código:

WebService:

```
package com.rodasdo;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Path("/oi")
public class Trator {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String returnTitle(){
        return "Tripa de Galinha azeda";
    }
}
```

MainActivity Android:

```
package com.example.consultasitio;

import com.example.consultasitio.ConsultaSituacao.ConstultaSituacaoSitioListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConstultaSituacaoSitioListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ConsultaSituacao(this).execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConsultaConcluida(String situacaositio) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.what);
        text.setText(situacaositio);

    }
}
```

Classe que conecta com o ws:

```
package com.example.consultasitio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class ConsultaSituacao extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ConstultaSituacaoSitioListener listener;

    private static final String URL_STRING = "http://192.168.1.9:8080/Servidorincompleto/oi";



    public ConsultaSituacao (ConstultaSituacaoSitioListener listener) {
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try {
            String resultado = consultaServidor();

            return interpretaresultado(resultado);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String interpretaresultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

        object.getJSONObject(resultado);

        return "O texto que voltou é:" + resultado;

    }

    private String consultaServidor() throws IOException {

        InputStream is = null;

        try {


            URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setReadTimeout(1000);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            conn.connect();

            conn.getResponseCode();

            is=conn.getInputStream();

            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            char[] buffer = new char[22];
            reader.read(buffer);

            return new String(buffer);
        } finally {

            if (is !=null){

                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        listener.onConsultaConcluida(result);

    }

    public interface ConstultaSituacaoSitioListener {

        void onConsultaConcluida(String situacaositio);

    }

}
```

Xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/what"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Erro do logcat:

> > 07-27 10:56:19.210: I/Choreographer(1790): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> >     07-27 10:56:19.970: D/dalvikvm(1790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 241K, 10% free 2964K/3272K, paused 112ms, total 112ms
> >     07-27 10:56:20.020: W/System.err(1790): org.json.JSONException: No value for Tripa de Galinha azeda
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:574)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at com.example.consultasitio.ConsultaSituacao.interpretaresultado(ConsultaSituacao.java:57)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at com.example.consultasitio.ConsultaSituacao.doInBackground(ConsultaSituacao.java:35)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at com.example.consultasitio.ConsultaSituacao.doInBackground(ConsultaSituacao.java:1)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
> >     07-27 10:56:20.030: W/System.err(1790):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Encontrei o erro /o/.

Alterei o método:
 
 private String interpretaresultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

        object.getJSONObject(resultado);

        return "O texto que voltou é:" + resultado;

para :

private String interpretaresultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {
  
  
  return resultado;

________________

XD, Obg.

Comment: Ah... Estava montando a resposta enquanto postou que resolveu o problema =/ Mas acho que sua tentativa apenas retarda o erro... De uma olhada na minha resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, vou analisá-la com atenção. :D

Comment: Ah entendi. Meu WS não estava gerando um JSON, mas sim apenas uma string. Por isso quando eu tirei aqueles códigos tinha funfado, mas não da forma que eu esperava. Contudo, após adicionar suas alterações, o WS passou a gerar corretamente um JSON, e o Android conseguiu interpretar. XD. Só precisei alterar o (char[22]) para (char[39]). Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem dois problemas:

1. Está retornando uma `String` que não está em formato `JSON` de um *WebService* que deveria retornar `JSON`. Para isso teria que fazer:

   ```
   package com.rodasdo;

   import javax.ws.rs.Path;
   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
   import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

   @Path("/oi")
   public class Trator {

       @GET
       @Produces("application/json")
       public String returnTitle(){
           // Retorno JSON
           return "{\"resposta\": \"Tripa de Galinha azeda\"}";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Está fazendo tratando a resposta do `WebService` de forma incorreta. Não está convertendo a `String` de resposta em objeto de forma correta. Para isso teria que construir o `JSON` a partir da variável `resultado` e recuperar o campo `resposta` (que possui o texto que precisa). Dessa forma:

   ```
   private String interpretaresultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {

       // Usar o construtor do JSONObject para "parsear" e representar o JSON na memória
       JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultado);

       return "O texto que voltou é: " + object.getString("resposta");
   }
   ```